# How to display a link only for logged in users?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using dotnetnuke version 5.4. I want to display a link after the terms of use and privacy statement (at the bottom).

**This link should be displayed only after a user logged in.** Is there is any way to do this? I know how to add a link to the `skin.ascx` file, but I don't know how to identify whether a user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 10):

In your skin, just add the following in the appropriate place.

**VB.NET**

```
<% If Request.IsAuthenticated %>
    [Logged in]
<% End If %>
```

**C#**

```
<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
    [Logged in]
<% } %>
```

This will show the "[Logged in]" text only if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would probably be to put the link in an HTML module that is in the footer pane and set it visible only to registered users, and visible on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated=True Then    %>

   <!-- put your stuff here -->


<% End If %>
```

Stick that in your skin, that should do it.